# Weird behavior with multiple objects of the same class in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working with Sprite Kit for iOS.
So I have this part of a button class for Sprite Kit:

```
#pragma Touch Events setup
- (void) setTouchDownAction:(SEL)action OnTarget:(id)target
{
    touchDownTarget = target;
    touchDownAction = action;
}

- (void) setTouchUpAction:(SEL)action OnTarget:(id)target
{
    touchUpTarget = target;
    touchUpAction = action;
}

#pragma Touch Handling
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];


    if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint))
        [self setSelected:YES];

    if(touchDownTarget && touchDownAction && CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint))
    {

        objc_msgSend(touchDownTarget, touchDownAction);
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

    if(touchUpTarget && touchUpAction && CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint))
    {
        [self setSelected:NO];
        objc_msgSend(touchUpTarget, touchUpAction);
    }
}
```

And I create an object of the class like this:

```
SKButton *onePlayerButton = [[SKButton alloc] initWithTexture:menuButtonTexture selectedTexture:menuButtonSelectedTexture size:CGSizeMake(buttonWidth, buttonWidth / 6)];
onePlayerButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height - 150);
onePlayerButton.color = [UIColor blueColor];
onePlayerButton.colorBlendFactor = 0.4;
[onePlayerButton setTitle:@"1 Player"];
[onePlayerButton setTouchUpAction:@selector(onePlayerButtonClicked) OnTarget:self];
[self addChild:onePlayerButton];
```

And if I create a second object of the same class and tap on the second or on the first button, both of the objects respond as clicked.

In the scene I get the touch events like this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [onePlayerButton touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [multiplayerButton touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [onePlayerButton touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [multiplayerButton touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Why do both objects respond?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that no matter where the user touch, you are sending touches to your buttons at the same time.

try to add a name to your buttons like this:

```
onePlayerButton.name = @"one_player";
multiplayerButton.name = @"mul_player";
```

now in touchesBegan add the event only when the user touch the button

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"one_player"])
    {
        [onePlayerButton touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"mul_player"])
    {
        [multiplayerButton touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

and that should work for you, is already tested.

Good Luck!

Comment: Okay. That solved the problem for the buttons. But the other problem is, that I have thumbsticks to navigate the player. But there is the problem that the touch is only at the beginning of the move in the node. And then it could be outside. So I detect the touch in touchMoved:event: So I have the same problem as before...